# Haversine formula returns null in Query

Tags: mysql, database, distance

```
SELECT 
    id,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.509980) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-0.133700 ) ) + sin( radians(51.509980) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM tbl_event 
HAVING distance < 5 
ORDER BY distance
```

Here -0.133700 is creating problem, other minus values like -122 etc. are working fine with this.

Please help if anyone is aware of this issue.

Comment: in above query ii is not  showing any issue with -0.133700  select ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.509980) ) * cos( radians( 0.0 ) ) * cos( radians( 0.0 ) - radians(-0.133700 ) ) + sin( radians(51.509980) ) * sin(radians(0.0)) ) ) AS distance

Comment: simple i replace your lat long with 0.0 and check its working may be an issue with your lat, lng coordinates available on DB can you share those informations

Comment: Thanks Mahesh Madushanka for your comment. I am aware with the fact that there is no problem in formula.Basically I want 0 distance events from my database and i am having 2 entries with same lat long values which is 51.50998 (lat) and -0.1337 (long). My current location lat long are also the same and it should return 0 as distance value but it is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns null because acos function get an argument greater than 1 or lower than -1. Try this :

```
Select id, 3959 * acos(if(d>1, 1, if(d<-1, -1, d))) as distance
From (SELECT id,
 cos( radians(51.509980) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-0.133700 ) ) + sin( radians(51.509980) ) * sin(radians(lat))  AS d
FROM tbl_event ) t1
HAVING distance < 5 
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: oohh great Msf vtp thanks it is returning 0. Thank you so much

Comment: @Bhumika My pleasure. ☺